# How to mute Android Virtual Device with ADB

Tags: android, adb, appium, android-virtual-device

I can change the volume of the Android device by sending key events to the device using Appium automation tool (which uses ADB?). I have not found a way to mute the virtual device. Mute can be toggled via the GUI and is independent of the virtual device volume. How can I mute the device?

**edit**

specifically I can enable must via the GUI by clicking the "bell" icon which if I hover my cursor over displays the test "mute calls and notifications".

Comment: Usually when you send volume down events to the device, the volume gets lower to the minimum and after that toggles to vibrate and then to silent. Isn't that the case with your AVD?

Comment: It's not the case with my avd. On the avd mute is mode.